# Access to health device in custom application

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-fit, hardware

Its my first question and I hope I do good. I am working on my research experiment, and I have almost zero knowledge on programming with hardware devices.

I am developing an application for `monitoring blood pressure or pulse rate/skin temperature (as in wrist bands)`. I want to use the `Bluetooth` connectivity. I have done my research and I found that most of the devices come with their own application, some can be connected with the `Google Fit`. A product [from](http://angelsensor.com/store/angel-sensor-m1/) provides open access to sensors but that is currently out of stock.

Since I have to buy the product for my experiment and my advisor has to fund it for me, I don't want to be embarrassed later on telling them that it is not supported for custom app development.

My question is that, is it possible that any blood pressure monitor that uses Bluetooth as a mode of communication can be used in my custom developed application for Android?

Comment: Yes it can be used, I had used a custom made hardware to measure BP, ECG, Temperature, SPO2 in my previous project

Comment: can you tell me or suggest the name for the BP monitor you have used so I may go for that instead of wondering on the net. Actually, I don't need to make the custom hardware, I need to integrate any available hardware in and app I am developing.

Comment: As we made our own hardware, I did pairing with those devices via bluetooth and used to start the measurement. Measuring algo was written in C. Since you dont need your custom hardware have a look at [this](http://www.pyleaudio.com/sku/PHBPBW40BK/Bluetooth-SMART-Wrist-Blood-Pressure-Monitor-with-Free-Downloadable-Health-Tracking-App-and-Adjustable-Strap,-Safe-for-All-Ages-(Black-Color)) might help

Comment: ok thanks @pooja, i am just curious that they might use encrypted bluetooth communication which only their app can understand. or is it not possible

Comment: Try to research more on it they might be allowing